# Layout margins on different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

**Layouts different screens**

As we all used to know, with designing one layout for specificated screen size, there is always screen sizes, that with the same layout doesn't have all the elements (*TextViews, ImageViews etc.*) in the correct spaces.

Here is **an example:**

[Layout in the Nexus 6P and Galaxy J5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noF62.png)

and

[Same layout in the Samsung Galaxy S6 and S5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRch6.png)

XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Results">




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/warning"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/warning"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/healthcircle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/healthcircle" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Waist circumference"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BMI"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="BMI Score"
        android:onClick="bmi"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/healthcircle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="N/A"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:onClick="bmi"
        android:id="@+id/BMI"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="N/A"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/warning1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/warning1"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/warning"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/healthcircle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/healthcircle" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/healthcircle"
        android:src="@drawable/healthcircle1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />






    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:onClick="profile"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"

         />




</RelativeLayout>
```

*...And when looking into those pictures, I was designing for Samsung Galaxy J5 and Nexus, but when running the app in Galaxy S5 and S6, "BMI Score" is in the wrong place... I have done many changes according to the "A"-picture place so that the BMI Score would fit in Galaxy S5 and S6..."*

Comment: Share your layout code

Comment: Would it be OK with a layout in which the big circle image covers the upper half of the screen and the rest below it?

Comment: Also, in your layout use `@+id/viewName` only when you are referencing or creating a view for the first time. For later simply refer the view using `@id/viewName`

Comment: Thats only thing i am trying to achieve in for as many screen sizes as possible so yeah

Comment: Ok thanks for achieve

Comment: I mean tip. .. sorry

Comment: Since, your views in the layout were named a bit generically and placed randomly in the file, it was getting difficult for me to follow properly. I'm just posting an answer with pseudocode. Let me know if you face any issues. Another tip: name your variables VERY carefully and use as many comments as possible. If your are on Android Studio, press Alt+Ctrl+L to automatically reformat your code to increase readability.

Comment: Ok ill test your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To design a layout which shows the circle image at the top half followed by the other stuff in the bottom half, you can refer to the following layout [psudocode]:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout ...
        android:layout_weight="1">

        // Circle Image with center alignment and textView above it 
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout...
        android:layout_weight="1">

        // All other views here

    </RelativeLayout>      

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
Here's the entire formatted layout code on your request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/healthcircle"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/healthcircle1"/>


    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/warning"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BMI"
            android:src="@drawable/warning"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/BMI"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="Waist circumference"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:onClick="bmi"
            android:text="BMI Score"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BMI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="bmi"
            android:text="N/A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView19"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="N/A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/warning1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView20"
            android:src="@drawable/warning"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:onClick="profile"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: doesn't still achieve the wanted places... but thanks for helping

Comment: Why? Its pretty straightforward. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Its very hard to remake the whole layout with that

Comment: I can try, if only your views are named properly :). I think at least you should try. Changes like these are needed to  to accomodate device fragmentation and the approach I suggested definitely guarantees a unified look. Its not required for you to use `<FrameLayout>` and `<RelativeLayout>` as child viewgroups, you can use others too.

Comment: So... Should I replace my RelativeLayout with Linear?

Comment: Because when doing that it like

Comment: it won't in the beginning of course. It will need a bit of rearranging. And yes your root layout should be `LinearLayout` as it allows us to divide the screen into two equal parts. Just give it a bit of time, it'll work.

Comment: I know, but still Linear divides the screen into 6 parts and it cannot fit the A pic to the center...

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. The root 'LinearLayout' will just have to children both with equal weights so they take equal space vertically. It is within these children that we place our other views.

Comment: Well... Ok. Ill test that in the morning

Comment: If you would Add my elements in to those LinearLayouts and frames, it would be more easily to recreate my activity

Comment: @Onhar I've recreated the entire layout file for you. A simple copy-paste should be OK. However, you should practice these more yourselves. It would really help you in the long run.

Comment: Yeah thanks mate... I am completely zero on these layout design things... Coding is my main job :) but thanks alot!